# Let $m,n$ be integers that satisfy $m^2+3m^2n^2=30n^2+517.$ Find $3m^2n^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

I first tried to use the quadratic equation to get values for $m$ and $n$, but that turned out to bee too long and complicated of a process. Is there any other way i can solve the equation? Completing the square, maybe?

Comment: Hint : Substitute $u=m^2$ and $v=n^2$ to get an easier equation

Comment: $(m^2-10)(3n^2+1)=507$.

Comment: also, the prime decomposition of $507 = 3\cdot 13^2$ might be useful.

Comment: I still have trouble figuring the answer even after all the hints...

Comment: Can you represent 507 as a product of two numbers, to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accordance with comments of Thomas Andrews and Student,
$$(m^2-10)(3n^2+1) = 3\cdot13^2.$$
Then, 
$$\begin{cases}
3\not|\ 3n^2+1,\\
m^2-10 \not= 3,\\
\end{cases}$$
so the only solution with
$$3n^2+1 = 13,\quad m^2-10 = 39,$$
or $3n^2 = 12, m^2=49,$
is possible.
$4$ and $49$ are squares, so $3m^2n^2 = 12\cdot 49,$
$$\boxed{3m^2n^2 = 588}.$$